# How can I easily link to a bunch of files in my Google Drive from a Google Sheet (in the same account/drive)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, links

I have a bunch of PDF files in a single folder (say "myPDFs") in my Google Drive.

I have a Google Sheet stored in the same Google Drive. One column of this Sheet has the filenames of the PDF files. (eg: "apple.pdf", "banana.pdf", etc.) I would like to transform each of these into a link to the corresponding file.

I know I can use the `hyperlink` function to create a link from a URL and link text, but the URL for the files (what Drive calls the "shareable link") is not easily computable from the filename. eg: `myPDFs/apple.pdf` might have a URL like `https://drive.google.com/open?id=Ia18d1uTYY5jfdyrhodAJ7Xofk4g0bLm5`. I do not want to have to manually retrieve the "shareable link" from the Drive UI, as there are several hundred files involved.

I tried making a custom function that uses `DriveApp.getFilesByName` to find the URL for each filename, but apparently that function cannot be called from a custom function.

How can I easily link to these files from my sheet?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link. This is the [Updated General version](https://pastebin.com/xeaKNPCk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 2nd EDIT

*(following OP's request) "I need a solution that gets me all the way from having a list of filenames (what I have now) to having a list of links I can click on and get to the corresponding file. Incomplete answers like "write a custom menu that uses DriveApp.getFilesByName" won't be accepted"*

**1.** On the spreadsheet's menu find `Tools` and click on `Script editor`.

**2.** Delete all content there and replace it with the following script.

```
function ListFldPdfs() {
  // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  // replace SHEET-NAME with the name of the sheet that will hold the list
  var myPDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER-ID'); // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  var thesheet = 'SHEET-NAME' // give a name to YOUR list sheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet); 
     if (!newPDFsheet) { 
       ss.insertSheet(thesheet, 0); 
       var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet) ;
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());
     }
  // clear all existing content
  newPDFsheet.clear();
  // append the header row
  newPDFsheet.appendRow([ "Name", "VIEW", "HYPERLINK"]);
  var results = [];
  // list all pdf files in the folder
  var mypdfs = myPDFfolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  // loop through found files in the folder
  while (mypdfs.hasNext()) { 
    var myfile = mypdfs.next(); 
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    results = [ fname, furl, ];
    //Logger.log("results = "+results); // for de-bugging
    newPDFsheet.appendRow(results); 
       } 
     var fcell = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet).getRange("C2"); 
               fcell.setFormula('=arrayformula(if(A2:A10="",,hyperlink(B2:B10,""&A2:A10&"")))'); 
}
```

**3.** Replace the `FOLDER-ID` with the ID of the folder to be searched and the `SHEET-NAME` with a name of your choice.

**4.** Save and authorize the code by clicking the `Advanced` button.

**5.** Run the script.

**What the script does**
When run for the first time, it creates a new sheet (`'SHEET-NAME'`) placing it in front of the rest of the sheets, where you get the name of the file (`Name`) in the specified folder(`'FOLDER-ID'`), the view URL of the file (`VIEW`) as well as the hyperlink to it (`HYPERLINK`).
After that and whenever you choose to re-run it (because you have maybe made some changes to the folder like added more files), it deletes just the content of the sheet (`'SHEET-NAME'`) and repeats the process on the same sheet. *(We avoid using an `onOpen` or `onEdit` trigger for the script because it would be an overstrain)*

---

**Initial answer**

*(Hoping I have not misunderstood your question)*

One of the functions in Google Sheets is `HYPERLINK`. It creates a hyperlink inside a cell. It's syntax is:


```
HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])
```

In your case it would be:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXXXX/", "banana.pdf")
```

Place the formula in a cell and when clicking on it, it will take you (since it is a `.pdf`) to the preview (since it is a `.pdf`) of the file. Repeat for as many files as you have.
You can read more about the `HYPERLINK` function [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313).

***TIP***: Because it is the shareable link, you have to **use the full URL** and not just the file ID.

---

### EDIT

*(following OP explanation)*

As a workaround, you can use the following script:

```
// replace FOLDER-NAME below with the folder for which you want a listing
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'FOLDER-NAME';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;
```

var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );

var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );
  }
};

It will create a new spreadsheet in the root directory *(`My Drive`)* with the folder's name *(`listing of folder FOLDER-NAME`)* where you will find all file names from the folder in question along with their URL.
You can then use a simple formula **(`=QUERY(A:B, "select * where A matches '.*pdf.*'",1)`)** to filter out just the files you need.

Comment: The URL ending `/view?usp=sharing` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I got the impression that the OP wants a program that will output the hyperlinks, without having to do each one manually.

Comment: @ahorn _"the OP wants a program that will output the hyperlinks"_. The more I read, the more I think you are right. Let's wait though for the OP to decide.

Comment: OP here: yes, the issue I'm having is with finding the URL that corresponds to each filename. I'll try to edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @marikamitsos If your edit is changing so much the answer, it's better to post a new answer.

Comment: This isn't quite the approach I was expecting -- you're creating a link to each file in the folder, while I was asking for a way to turn a bunch of filenames in the sheet into links. That said, I can definitely work with this, and it may even have some benefits over the way I was originally planning on using it. Thanks!

Comment: Alhamdulillah, Thanks,  Saved my day for 610 files.