# Link audio files in Google Drive folder in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive

I have hundreds of audio files (.mp3) in a Google Drive folder that I need to list with links in a Google Sheet. Very similar to the problem described [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135181/how-can-i-easily-link-to-a-bunch-of-files-in-my-google-drive-from-a-google-sheet), but I was not able to adapt the code to .mp3 files. The example code that I adapted:

```
function ListFldPdfs() {
  // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  // replace SHEET-NAME with the name of the sheet that will hold the list
  var myPDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER-ID'); // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  var thesheet = 'SHEET-NAME' // give a name to YOUR list sheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet); 
     if (!newPDFsheet) { 
       ss.insertSheet(thesheet, 0); 
       var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet) ;
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());
     }
  // clear all existing content
  newPDFsheet.clear();
  // append the header row
  newPDFsheet.appendRow([ "Name", "VIEW", "HYPERLINK"]);
  var results = [];
  // list all pdf files in the folder
  var mypdfs = myPDFfolder.getFilesByType('audio/mp3');
  // loop through found files in the folder
  while (mypdfs.hasNext()) { 
    var myfile = mypdfs.next(); 
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    results = [ fname, furl, ];
    //Logger.log("results = "+results); // for de-bugging
    newPDFsheet.appendRow(results); 
       } 
     var fcell = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet).getRange("C2"); 
               fcell.setFormula('=arrayformula(if(A2:A10="",,hyperlink(B2:B10,""&A2:A10&"")))'); 
}
```

This code effectively creates a new sheet in my Google Sheet with the columns Name, VIEW and HYPERLINK, but without listing the actual files in the original folder or providing links to see them. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. If the script throw an error message add it textually, also add the logs.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. There is no error message, the script just does not give me the desired output. I only get the column names (Name, VIEW, HYPERLINK) in the sheet, but I don't get the audio files names or links in the remaining rows.

Comment: Try `audio/mpeg` instead of `audio/mp3`

Comment: Have a look at [Google Drive mime-types listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14547355/1330560) on StackOverflow. The linked answer shows the relationship between many file extensions and mine types. Other answers to this question also provide useful relevant information.

Comment: I also use scripts for Google Drive based on `appendRow()`. Today I wondered about the ineffiency of that method. I modified a script to use temporary arrays and write output once. In a folder of @750 spreadsheets, an `appendRow()` script takes about 3 minutes; the equivalent array script took about 20 seconds. Yikes! This made me wonder about inefficiencies in my day-to-day coding. I think I shall kick off by looking through [Taking Advantage of Google Apps Script (Tanaike's list)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-google-apps-script#benchmarks) by @Tanaike.

Comment: Thank you @Tedinoz, the `audio/mpeg` makes the code work as intended in the original code.

Comment: @Crimc Why not post an answer to your own question. It'll ensure that users having a similar problem can consider include your question in their research.

Answer (score 1):

The following minor change to the right mime-type files solves the issue:

```
function ListFldPdfs() {
  // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  // replace SHEET-NAME with the name of the sheet that will hold the list
  var myPDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER-ID'); // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  var thesheet = 'SHEET-NAME' // give a name to YOUR list sheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet); 
     if (!newPDFsheet) { 
       ss.insertSheet(thesheet, 0); 
       var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet) ;
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());
     }
  // clear all existing content
  newPDFsheet.clear();
  // append the header row
  newPDFsheet.appendRow([ "Name", "VIEW", "HYPERLINK"]);
  var results = [];
  // list all mp3 files in the folder
  var mypdfs = myPDFfolder.getFilesByType('audio/mpeg');
  // loop through found files in the folder
  while (mypdfs.hasNext()) { 
    var myfile = mypdfs.next(); 
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    results = [ fname, furl, ];
    //Logger.log("results = "+results); // for de-bugging
    newPDFsheet.appendRow(results); 
       } 
     var fcell = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet).getRange("C2"); 
               fcell.setFormula('=arrayformula(if(A2:A10="",,hyperlink(B2:B10,""&A2:A10&"")))'); 
}
```